# .Net core 3.1 return RedirectToPage("SomePage") not working as expecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am on the Dashboard page where I have inherited my base class, which is expecting redirection based on value. I actually don't want to display page of value is 0. Below is the code.

This is the main page I don't want to execute the `OnGet()` on the dashboard page. Before that, I have to check some values on HostBasePage

```
[Area("BusinessHost")]
[Authorize(Roles ="Host")]
public class dashboardModel : HostBasePage
{
    public dashboardModel(IAccountBusinessRepository accountBusinessRepository, ISessionManager sessionManager)
    : base(accountBusinessRepository, sessionManager) { }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

This is my base class and I want to go to the "AccountSetup" page.

```
public class HostBasePage : PageModel
{
    private readonly IAccountBusinessRepository _accountBusinessRepository;
    private readonly ISessionManager _sessionManager;
    public HostBasePage(IAccountBusinessRepository accountBusinessRepository, ISessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
        _accountBusinessRepository = accountBusinessRepository;
         ValidateAccount();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Validate Host account. 
    /// Account setup and payment needs to me complated.  
    /// </summary>
    private async Task<IActionResult> ValidateAccount()
    {
        try
        {
            var accountID = _sessionManager.GetSessionValue("AccountID");
          

            HostProfileValidateModel obj = await _accountBusinessRepository.HostProfileValidate(Convert.ToInt32(accountID));

            if (obj.IsAccountSetup == 0) { 
                return RedirectToPage("AccountSetup");
            }
                
          
            //if (obj.IsPaid == 0)
            //    throw new Exception("");

            return
                Page();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
       
    }
```

If `obj.IsAccountSetup` is 0, I need redirection. No error is comming right now, but it's not redirecting to the AccountSetup page.

This is the page I want to display.

```
[Area("BusinessHost")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Host")]
public class AccountSetupModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IAccountBusinessRepository _accountBusinessRepository;
    private readonly IServiceBusinessRepository _serviceBusinessRepository;
    private readonly ICategoryBusinessRepository _categoryBusinessRepository;
    private readonly IFranchiseBusinessRepository _franchiseBusinessRepository;
    private readonly ISessionManager _sessionManager;
    private readonly IPlansBusinessRepository _plansBusinessRepository;
    private readonly IBusinessHostAccountSetupRepository _businessHostAccountSetupRepository;
    public AccountSetupModel(IBusinessHostAccountSetupRepository businessHostAccountSetupRepository, IAccountBusinessRepository accountBusinessRepository,IPlansBusinessRepository plansBusinessRepository , ISessionManager sessionManager, ICategoryBusinessRepository categoryBusinessRepository, IServiceBusinessRepository serviceBusinessRepository, IFranchiseBusinessRepository franchiseBusinessRepository)
    {
        _accountBusinessRepository = accountBusinessRepository;
        _serviceBusinessRepository = serviceBusinessRepository;
        _categoryBusinessRepository = categoryBusinessRepository;
        _franchiseBusinessRepository = franchiseBusinessRepository;
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
        _businessHostAccountSetupRepository = businessHostAccountSetupRepository;
        _plansBusinessRepository = plansBusinessRepository;

    }
    public async void OnGet()
    {
        string email = _sessionManager.GetSessionValue("RegisterEmail");
        ModelServiceModel = new ServicesModel();
        ModelCategoryModel = new ServicesModel();
        ModelFranchiseModel = new FranchiseModel();
        GetAllAccountData();
        GetAllCategories();
        GetAllServices();
        GetAllFranchise();
        PlansModel = await _plansBusinessRepository.GetAllPlans();
        if (PlansModel != null)
        {
            PlansModel.TotalAmmount = PlansModel.AccountSetupCharges + PlansModel.MonthlyCharges + PlansModel.FrontDeskCharges;
        }
    }
    public void GetAllCategories()
    {
        var data = _categoryBusinessRepository.GetAllCategoriesList();
        ModelServiceModel.Category = data.Result.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Convert.ToString(x.CategoryName),
            Value = Convert.ToString(x.CategoryID)

        }).ToList();
    }
   


}
```

Comment: I already tried these too:-    return RedirectToPage("/AccountSetup", new { area = "BusinessHost" });

and  

 return RedirectToPage("/AccountSetup");

Comment: where is AccountSetup in relation to this page or root?

Comment: @ATerry it's in relation to this page, I have a business host area and both page "dashboard" and "AccountSetup" are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just implement `OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync` methods in your `PageModel` like

```
public class HostBasePage : PageModel
{
    private readonly IAccountBusinessRepository _accountBusinessRepository;
    private readonly ISessionManager _sessionManager;
    public HostBasePage(IAccountBusinessRepository accountBusinessRepository, ISessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
        _accountBusinessRepository = accountBusinessRepository;
    }

    public override async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            var accountID = _sessionManager.GetSessionValue("AccountID");

            HostProfileValidateModel obj = await _accountBusinessRepository.HostProfileValidate(Convert.ToInt32(accountID));

            if (obj.IsAccountSetup == 0)
            {
                context.Result = RedirectToPage("/AccountSetup", new { area = "BusinessHost" });
            }
            else
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-razor-page-filters-by-overriding-filter-methods

Comment: It is never correct to `throw ex;` within a catch block where `ex` is the caught exception. Doing so will cause the original stack trace to be lost, and replaced with the stack trace of the line where you `throw ex;` (which is useless). Simply write `throw;`.